# How do I slice an array with an i32 limit?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to slice an array with a dynamic boundary:

```
fn main() {
    let n: i32 = 2;
    let a = [1, 2, 3];
    println!("{:?}", &a[0..n]);
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> error: the trait bound `[_]: std::ops::Index<std::ops::Range<i32>>` is not satisfied

I don't know what to do with this error. It seems I can't use a `i32` to slice an array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check in [slice docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html) (search for `Index<Range`) that `Index` trait is only implemented for `usize` ranges, so you cannot use a `Range<i32>`.

One possibility is to cast the `i32` for `usize`:

```
fn main() {
    let n: i32 = 2;
    let a = [1,2,3];
    println!("{:?}", &a[0..n as usize]); 
}
```

but you should take care because the cast is not checked, a negative `i32` value can be cast to `usize` without an error. You can create a function to do a checked conversion or use a crate (for example [`num::ToPrimitive`](http://rust-num.github.io/num/num/trait.ToPrimitive.html)).

In the future, Rust will have [checked conversion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) in the standard library.

Comment: Really the correct answer is to try and store `n` as a `usize` as early on as possible. If it's some sort of user input, it should be parsed as a `usize`, as any negative number would be invalid for indexing.